# Re-create image from hex code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hexdump

We created an app on Android that a user can upload an image. The image is send through a post request on a Rails application as a bitmap. An example of what I get is [this](https://gist.github.com/stefioan/29a87622435c0527e4f2).

I want to use this hex code string in order to re-create the image and then save it to my Rails app as I could do with Paperclip.

Any tip or guidance to the right direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Just write `params[:file]` to  a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, this looks very much like a JPEG file (it starts with `0xFFD8FF`), so you could just save the string to a file and you're done:

```
class UploadsController

   def create
     storage_path.open('w') {|f| f.write params[:file] }
     head :ok
   end

protected

  def storage_path
    @storage_path ||= Rails.root.join('data/uploads', current_user.id, Time.now.to_i.to_s(36) << '.jpg')
  end
end
```

Of course, this assumes you have a `current_user` method identifying a logged-in user (e.g. from Devise), and you want to save the file locally in `$RAILS_ROOT/data/uploads/$USER_ID/`.

For production, I'd create an `Upload` (or `Image` (or `Media`)) model (`belongs_to :user`), and move the processing logic (i.e. find storage place, convert string to file, additional checks) into that class.